# How can I clean data frame with html?

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe which looks like this :

```
    text
0   "<p>ROA1<\/p>"
1   "<p>Supports de cours<\/p>"
2   "<p>Textes<\/p>"
3   "<p>Bonjour \u00e0 tous,&nbsp;<br><br>J'esp\u0...
4   "<p style=\"text-align:justify;\">Chers appren...
...
295 Rejoignez-moi <a href="/video/liv...
296 "Pr\u00e9sente"
297 Rejoignez-moi dans la réunion <a target='_blan...
298 "<p style=\"text-align:justify;\"><span style=...
299 "<p style=\"text-align:justify;\"><span style=...
```

I want to clean the text. I did this to remove everything bewtween tags :

```
df['text'] = df['text'].map(lambda x : re.sub('<[^>]+>', '', str(x)))
```

Now I'm trying to use unescape to convert unicode characters to string. For example I want to convert '\u00e0' to 'à'. I don't know how to apply this to the entire data frame column.

**UPDATE**

I found out about html2text. It seems to work well :

```
def html_to_string(text):
  text = html2text.html2text(text)

  return text
```

The output looks like this :

```
Bonjour à tous,  
  
J'espère que vous avez bien profité de la pause inter-semestres.  
Nous voici ensemble pour traverser le 2e Semestre.
```

This is exactly what I want so I tried to apply this to the dataframe.

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(html_to_string)
```

But it doesn't work on the dataframe, maybe I don't apply it correctly, here's the output :

```
    text
0   "\n\nROA1<\/p>"\n\n
1   "\n\nSupports de cours<\/p>"\n\n
2   "\n\nTextes<\/p>"\n\n
3   "\n\nBonjour \u00e0 tous, \n \nJ'esp\u00e8re...
4   "\n\nChers apprenants,<\/p>\n\n \nVous trouve...
... ...
295 Rejoignez-moi dans la Room [MISSIONS FANNY](/v...
296 "Pr\u00e9sente"\n\n
297 Rejoignez-moi dans la réunion [Marché des gemm...
298 "\n\nBonjour,<\/span> \n \n \nMerci d'\u00e...
299 "\n\nBonjour,<\/span> \n \n \nMerci d'\u00e..
```

Comment: Post dataframe as text not as screenshot.

Comment: Are you still stuck?

Comment: I tried to use html2text, I updated my post

Comment: `<\/p>` should not it be `<\p>` ??

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the text from the html use `soup.get_text()`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.get_text('\n'))
```

---

**syntax:**

```
df['text'].applymap(lambda text: BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser').get_text())
```